# msbuild is missing VSINSTALLDIR on build server

Tags: c++, mfc, msbuild

I've got an issue on our build server when trying to get our first C++ MFC project compiled. I've got a solution file with two projects in it. In Visual Studio 2010 a build definition has been created which uses the TFSBuild.proj file. In the TFSBuild.proj, the MFC solution is included. We do have a lot of C#.NET, VB.NET and database projects running successfully at this buildserver. Only this MFC project seems to fail now.

When the build definition is queued, msbuild starts compilation, but ends up with the message:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets (296): Could not find VCInstallDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
```

On the build server is Windows Server 2003 (32-bit) and Visual Studio 2010 is installed. When the VS Command prompt is opened an the environment variables are checked with the SET command, the VSINSTALLDIR is listed correctly.

I ran the build with the verbose level **Diagnostic** and see following information (only a couple of the settings):

```
Configuration = Debug
ConfigurationFlavor = Debug
ConfigurationName = Debug
ConfigurationType = Application
Platform = Win32
PlatformToolset = v100
PlatformToolsetVersion = 100
VS100COMNTOOLS = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
VS80COMNTOOLS = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\
VS90COMNTOOLS = c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
VSInstallDir = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
```

Why is it reporting that the VSINSTALLDIR cannot be found, although it shows in de logging that it is set correctly?

Comment: Read the message: *from the registry*.  A repair ought to be next, after checking that the machine is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hans, you pointed me in de right direction. I did a repair of the Visual Studio installation first, but without success. But then I checked the installed features and discovered that the C++ feature was not enabled at that build server :( (as said, we did not have a C++ project before at the build server). Then I installed the C++ feature and the problem is solved!